# Is the a function I can use inside a javascript file that can link to my index when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a webpage with working navigation bar links. The only links that need to work are my home link and my blog link, however when the home link is clicked it does not go back to my index file where everything is created.

I've tried linking the `home.js` file in my `index.html`, but it still acts like the `home.js` is its own page?

I was also thinking the problem may be in my `routeFw.js` file?

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Use this type of comment within HTML -->
    <title>Find Your Travel Buddy</title>

    <link href="style/commonStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <link href="style/lightTitleStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

    <style> 
        .callOut {
            margin:5ex;
            padding: 0.25ex 1ex;  /* first number is top/botom, then left/right */
            background-color: #ccb4b5;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="titleNav">

        <div id="pageTitle">
            Find Your Travel Buddy!

        </div>

        <div id="nav">

            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#/home"><img title="Home" src="icons/light/home_icon_H24.png" alt="Home"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <img class="dropHeader" title="Account"  onclick="myDropdown.toggle(this)" src="icons/light/account_dd_icon_H24.png" alt="Account" >
                <div class="dropContent" id="accountDropDown">
                    <a>Register</a> <br/>
                    <a>Log In</a> <br/>
                    <a>Profile</a> <br/>
                    <a>Log Out</a>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <img class="dropHeader" title="Search" onclick="myDropdown.toggle(this)" src="icons/light/search_dd_icon_H24.png" alt="Search" >
                <div class="dropContent" id="searchDropDown">
                    <a href="#/users">Users</a> <br/>
                    <a href="#/cars">Cars</a>  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <img class="dropHeader" title="Tutorial"  onclick="myDropdown.toggle(this)" src="icons/light/tutorial_dd_icon_H24.png" alt="Account" >
                <div class="dropContent" id="tutorialDropDown">
                    <a>Proposal</a> <br/>
                    <a>Demo</a> <br/>
                    <a>Log</a> <br/>
                </div> 
            </div>          
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#/blog"><img  title="Blog" src="icons/light/blog_icon_H24.png" alt="Blog"></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>  <!-- end of titleNav (keep track of nesting) -->

        <div id="content">

        <div class="callOut">
            <h2 align="center">
                Planning a trip?
            </h2>

            <p align="center">
                Want to enjoy your time and share your memories
                with someone? Your travel buddy is just one click away!
            </p>

            <p align="center">
                We our now offering a <strong>one week</strong>
                all exclusive trip to one of our selected locations. First-time
                users get a 20% off discount!!!
            </p>


            <h5 align="center">
                <a href='https://www.wellsfargo.com/go-far-rewards/'>Wells Fargo</a>
                users are eligible to redeem their rewards points with our services.
            </h5> <!-- wells fargo becomes a link -->

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class='column column66'>

                <strong>Never been to Italy?</strong> Seeing some of the world's
                most famous sights certainly tops everyone's list when traveling 
                in Italy. But taking part in an activity or trying something new, 
                especially something you can share with locals, adds a special 
                dimension to a trip.
                <br/>
                <p>
                    With you travel buddy, you can:
                <p><strong>Hike the Cinque Terre</strong></p>
                <p><strong>Glide Through Venice in a Gondola</strong></p>
                <p><strong>Tour Tuscan Hill Towns by Bicycle or Car</strong></p>
                <p><strong>Make Perfect Pasta in Florence</strong></p>
                <p><strong>Step Inside Ancient Rome</strong></p>

                </p>
            </div>

            <div class='column column33'>
                <img src='pics/italy.jpg' alt="Italy">
            </div>
            <div class='stopFloat'></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class='column column33'>
                <img src='pics/japan.jpg' alt='Japan'>
            </div>

            <div class='column column66'>
                <strong>日本に来て (Come to Japan!) </strong>Japan is known
                worldwide for its traditional arts, including tea ceremonies,
                calligraphy and flower arranging. The country has a legacy of
                distinctive gardens, sculpture and poetry. Japan is home to
                more than a dozen UNESCO World Heritage sites and is the
                birthplace of sushi, one of its most famous.
            </div>

            <div class='stopFloat'></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class='column column66'>
                <strong>What about Turkey?</strong> Turkey is noted for having one of the
                three most famous and distinctive traditional cuisines in
                the world. The First Ecumenical Council was held in Iznik,
                Turkey. Writing was first used by people in ancient Anatolia.
                The first clay tablets in the ruins of Assyrian Karum 
                (Merchant Colony) date back to 1950 B.C.
            </div>

            <div class='column column33'>
                <img src='pics/turkey.jpg' alt='Turkey'>
            </div>
            <div class='stopFloat'></div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- content. [[Keep track of nesting]] -->


    <div id="footer">
        Nyla Rashied
    </div>

    <div id="view"></div>

    <script src="js/dropdownFw.js"></script>

    <script src="js/routeFw.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/blog.js"></script>     
    <script src="js/components/home.js"></script>

    <script>

                    "use strict";
                    var myRoutes = [];

                    myRoutes['/'] = home;  // home is a function stored in js/components/home.js
                    myRoutes['/home'] = home;
                    myRoutes['/blog'] = blog;


                    // routeFw returns a routing object that has private and public 
                    // data members and methods. 
                    // As input parameter, it takes an object with properties you can set 
                    // or just accept whatever defaults are set by the framework.
                    var myRoutes = routeFw({
                        routeArray: myRoutes,
                        //startingPath: '/home',
                        contentId: "content"
                    });

                    // print the routes (check console.log)
                    myRoutes.printRoutes();

                    var myDropdown = dropDownFw({
                        dropContentStyle: "dropContent",
                        hiddenRight: "-500px"
                    });

    </script>
</body>
```

**home.js**:

```
function home(id) {
    var content = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;
}
```

**routeFw.js**:

```
function routeFw(params) {

var fw = {}; // creating and adorning this object to be passed back to the HTML page.

var startingPath = params.startingPath || '/home';
var contentId = params.contentId || "view";

if (!params.routeArray || params.routeArray[0]) {
    alert("parameter object must specify array 'routeArray' with at least one element");
    return;
}

// Declare a (private) array to store our routes.
var routes = params.routeArray;

// private function that will be called whenever a link is clicked (or href changed)
function router() { // private function

    console.log("location.hash (the link that was clicked) is " + location.hash);
    // prints something like #/home

    // remove leading # from string that holds the clicked link
    var path = location.hash.slice(1) || '/';
    console.log('path (with no #) is ' + path);
    // prints something like /home

    // Use the url like an index (JS associative array notation) to find 
    // the desired content and place it in the content area.
    // document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = routes[url];
    if (!routes[path]) {
        document.getElementById(contentId).innerHTML = "Error: link '" + path +
                "' was never added to the routing.";
    } else {
        // invoke the function that's specified by the ajaxFillId(routes[url], "view");
        // pass the correct route object to that function (either staticContent or jsonContent)
        routes[path](contentId); // invoke function routes[path], a JS funtion/component
    }
}

fw.printRoutes = function () {
    console.log("routes will be printed on the next line ");
    console.log(routes);
};

// Listen on hash change (whenever a link is clicked or href changed)
// In other words, whenever a link is clicked, invoke function router.
window.addEventListener('hashchange', router);

// content for when page is first rendered.
window.location.hash = startingPath;

return fw;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried removing the hash from the href so it’s just “/“ or “/home”?

Comment: Not sure whether you can see this as you don't have much SO kudos/points yet - but you can normally edit you post as natural HTML/CSS/JavaScript in SO - use the icon that looks like <>. Then you can see it inline in the page

Comment: @mlunt when I removed the hash from href, it showed a new page that said file not found.

Comment: `var content = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content;` is a rather weird line of code. you're setting the innerHTML of that element and content to.... content, which is undefined...

Comment: @KevinB Is there a way I can take what is in my index.html and just insert it into my home.js to make it show as my home page?